# Merge Quicklook and preview

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

Quicklook seems to be the official name for the preview.app functionality.

Please merge them, it's displaying me it needs at least+5 score in the tag to merge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Quicklook is what you get if you press <kbd>Space</kbd> in Finder to view the content of a file
- Preview.app is an application on its own

Unless I misunderstood your intention I don't think these two tags should get merged.

Comment: Indeed it appears to be true... no you're right. I meant Preview was Quicklook indeed.

Comment: You comment confuses me somewhat, Quicklook and Preview.app are 2 very different things, and I'm not sure if you have changed your mind, or think that Patrix agrees with you!  Can you clarify (sorry if I am being dim here)